# Find the values of $x$ which will make the following expression a perfect square: $x^4+ 6x^3+13x^2+13x-1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, problem-solving, factoring

$$x^4+ 6x^3+13x^2+13x-1=\textrm{perfect square}$$
I don't know how to approach this. I have tried to factor this but was unable to, and equating it to squares of numbers is a tedious process, and I am not sure how to solve this problem.

By the way, this question is from Elementary Algebra by Hall and Knight, Exercise XXX b question 15.

Comment: One way to cut down on the number of trials is to require the expression to be a quadratic residue modulo a number of smallish primes. E.g. mod $3$ your polynomial becomes $x^4 + x^2 + x - 1$, so we can rule out $x$ as multiples of $3$ because these would give a result $-1 \bmod 3$, which is not a quadratic residue.

Comment: Is there a perfect square that is *close* to your expression? A number of the form $(x^2+ax+b)^2$ perhaps?

Comment: In [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) run `IntegralQuarticPoints([1, 6, 13, 13, -1]);` and get two solutions.

Comment: Try $x=5$......

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : The answer is always 42 :-)

Comment: I removed the [tag:abstract-algebra] tag

Comment: That book  does not use modular arithmetic. In fact, the article before that problem explains how to find square roots of expressions like these. For anyone interested in posting a solution the book can be found at https://ia800302.us.archive.org/17/items/elementaryalgebr00hall/elementaryalgebr00hall_bw.pdf

Comment: Do you want $x$ to be a natural number?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Can you show that $(x^2+3x+2)^2<x^4+6x^3+13x^2+13x-1<(x^2+3x+3)^2$ for $x>5$?

(A suggestion in this direction was provided by [player3236](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/435724/player3236) in a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an expansion of
J. W. Tanner's answer.

According to Wolfram Alpha,

$\sqrt{x^4+ 6x^3+13x^2+13x-1}
=x^2\sqrt{1+ 6/x+13/x^2+13/x^3-1/x^4}
=x^2 + 3 x + 2 + 1/(2 x) + O((1/x)^2)
$.

This suggest seeing how close
$(x^2 + 3 x + 2)^2
$
is to
$x^4+ 6x^3+13x^2+13x-1
$.

We have
$x^4+ 6x^3+13x^2+13x-1-(x^2 + 3 x + 2)^2
=x-5
$
and
$x^4+ 6x^3+13x^2+13x-1-(x^2 + 3 x + 3)^2
=-2 x^2 - 5 x - 10
$
so,
if $x > 5$,
$(x^2 + 3 x + 2)^2
\lt x^4+ 6x^3+13x^2+13x-1
\lt (x^2 + 3 x + 3)^2
$
so that
$x^4+ 6x^3+13x^2+13x-1
$
can not be a square.

For $x$ from $1$ to $5$,
the values of
$x^4+ 6x^3+13x^2+13x-1
$
are
$| 32 | 141 | 398 | 899 | 1764
$
of which the only square is
$1764
=42^2
$
for $x=5$.

---

More generally,
again according to Wolfy,
$\sqrt{x^4+2ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}
=x^2 + a x + (b - a^2)/2 + (a^3 - a b + c)/(2 x) + O((1/x)^2)
$

so that
$x^4+2ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
-(x^2 + a x + (b - a^2)/2)^2
=(a^3-ab+c) x-1/4 a^4 + 1/2 a^2 b  + (-1/4) b^2  + d
$.

This shows that
$x^4+2ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
$
can be a square for
only a finite number of
integral $x$
unless
$(a^3-ab+c) =(-1/4 a^4 + 1/2 a^2 b  + (-1/4) b^2  + d)
=0
$
in which case
$x^4+2ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
=(x^2 + a x + (b - a^2)/2)^2
$.