# How many values of positive integers 'm' exist such that, $m^4 - 4m^3 + 22m^2 - 36m + 18$ is a perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, contest-math

I found this question in a math olympiad book. I figured that,

$m^4 - 4m^3 + 22m^2 - 36m + 18$ = $(m-1)^2(m^2 - 2m + 17) + 1$

But I don't know if I'm solving it the right way, and if yes, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911431/find-the-values-of-x-which-will-make-each-of-the-following-expression-a-perfec)

Comment: It should get a bit simpler if you substitute $n=m-1$

Comment: This question shows up many times when you search for it in [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24m%5E4%20-%204m%5E3%20%2B%2022m%5E2%20-%2036m%20%2B%2018%24&p=1).

Answer (score 2):

Note that we have:
$$
(x^2 -2x + 9)^2
=x^4 - 4x^3 + 22x^2 - 36x + 81\ ,
$$
and the previous square number is not far away.

Answer (score 1):

A different take on @dan_fulea's observation:

Let $b=m^2 -2m + 9$. Note that $b>0$.

If $m^4 - 4m^3 + 22m^2 - 36m + 18=a^2$, then $63=b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)$.

The only solutions with $b>0$ and $m \in \mathbb N$ are $(b,m)=(8,1)$ and $(b,m)=(12,3)$.

Bottom line: $m=1$ or $m=3$.